# I want to get the value of disabled text box in our next jsp but i am getting null value 

Tags: html, jsp

I want to get the value of disabled text box in our next jsp but I am getting a NULL value.
Any idea what might be going wrong?.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Input fields marked with [`disabled="disabled"`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.12.1) never send their value to the server when the form is posted. You could use the [`readonly="readonly"`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.12.2) attribute in order to still make the field not editable by the user but send the initial value to the server when the form is submitted.

Comment: @Lenin, according to the specification the value is `CI` (case insensitive). Personally I prefer using lowercase for all attribute names and values.

Comment: when i tried this with readonly it wasnt working 
document.getElementById('member_limit').readOnly=true;

Comment: @Lenin, what you have shown is the javascript attribute readonly for a given DOM element. Javascript is case sensitive and in this case you should indeed use `readOnly`. In my answer I was referring to the `readonly` attribute that you apply in your markup which is not the same thing. Also in your javascript you should better use `document.getElementById('member_limit').readOnly = 'readonly';` instead of `true` because according to the specification the correct value for this attribute is the `readonly` string and not a boolean value.

Comment: Thanks for your kind information. I used boolean there because i want to toggle that feild in some case.

Comment: @Lenin, you don't toggle a `readonly` field. If you want the field to no longer be `readonly` the proper way is to remove the `readonly` attribute.

Answer (score -1):

You can't get disable property value into server side. You need to run javascript to fetch disabled value into servlet.

Comment: Wow. And how about when the enduser has JS disabled? I'd rather use a `<input type="hidden">` as workaround for the case using the `readonly` attribute is not the solution for you.