# How to get the value of a disabled text field in jsp

Tags: java, html, eclipse, jsp

I am having a dropdown box and a 5 textfields( all disabled). I am entering data into textfield by using javascript, from the dropdown(what ever value is present in the dropdown, goes into the text fields).

Now, when the submit button is clicked, I want to get the value from this text field in the action class(java). On testing, I was getting "null" [getParameterValues("textfieldname") is what I have done].

When I removed the disabled, **I was getting the value**. So, how can I get the value while the disabled, is applied to the text field ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want to get the value of disabled text box in our next jsp but i am getting null value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757806/i-want-to-get-the-value-of-disabled-text-box-in-our-next-jsp-but-i-am-getting-nu)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Instead of disable them make them readonly.

```
<input type="text" name="nameOfTextField" readonly="readonly" />
```

Comment: Ok. So while they are disabled, we cant get the values ?

Comment: @Ajj : No you can't get value if it is disabled.

Comment: Oh ok. Wanted to confirm this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

if you want the field to be disabled you can use an hidden input like this:

```
<input type="text" id="nameVisible" disabled="disabled" />
<input type="hidden" name="nameObj" id="nameObj"/>
```

when you load page, you set value in both fields via DOM

in this way you'll see the input disabled on the page, and you'll get the hidden value when you submit it.

Comment: "you set value in both fields via DOM" ?? Sorry, dint understand this part. Novice

Answer (score 0):

If you still want text fields to be **disabled**, double them: one with disabled, other with hidden type.

Example:

```
<select name="selectedItem">
    <option value="1" selected>A</option>
    <option value="2" selected>B</option>
</select>

<input name="iname" value="${selectedItem}" disabled />
<input name="inameh" value="${selectedItem}" type="hidden" />
```

Now the **iname** field will be visible at site (disabled), and you can get the choosen value from **inameh** (hidden) with:

```
javascript: getParameterValues("inameh")
java: request.getParameterValues("inameh")
```