# Getting value of a disabled textbox in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am getting two numbers from users and then displaying their sum in a disabled textbox. I am also storing the inputs in my db.

Everything works fine. I can pass number1 and number2 to my database but i am not able to pass sum to db. I've spent too much time to solve this problem by myself but no luck.

Can you please check my code and let me know what i am missing here? What i want is to store sum into my db.

So this is my form:

```
    <p>Enter number1:</p>
    <input id="number1" name="number1"/>

    <p>Enter number2:</p>
    <input id="number2" name="number2"/>

    <p>Sum</p>
    <input id="sum" name="sum" disabled="disabled"/>
```

this is my script:

```
    var sum = (number1 + number2);
    $('#sum').val(sum);
```

and this is my php code:

```
    <?php
    ..connection info here..
    $number1 = $_POST['number1']; 
    $number2 = $_POST['number2']; 
    $sum = $_POST['sum']; 
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO mytable VALUES( '$number1', '$number2', '$sum')");
    if($stmt)
    echo "Done.";
    else
    echo "Error.";

    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
    $mysqli->close();
    ?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [I want to get the value of disabled text box in our next jsp but i am getting null value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757806/i-want-to-get-the-value-of-disabled-text-box-in-our-next-jsp-but-i-am-getting-nu)

Answer (score 13):

Disabled inputs are not included in form submissions. That is the point of disabling them.

You might want to use `readonly` instead.

Comment: It has a value, which you can get using JavaScript. The value isn't submitted when submitting the form.

Comment: Another thing worth considering: if you're computing values to show to the user in a read-only mode, I would think you could compute them again when the form is posted back to the server again.

Answer (score 5):

```
<input id="sum" name="sum" readonly="readonly"/>
```

So it will be included into submission and not let anyone edit the value too.

Answer (score 1):

Please reference this information:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3757816/6113439

Because you can't get any values of form control [`method='post'`] when you insert attribute `disabled='disabled'`.

You can use `readonly='readonly'` instead of `disabled='disabled'`